# Problem when defining a Logging trait in scala

Tags: scala, logging, traits

It seems that common logging pattern in scala is to use a Logging trait which is mixed with concrete class (cf. open source projects like Liftweb, akka, ...).

Something like that:

```
trait Logging {
  val loggerName = this.getClass.getName
  @transient lazy val log = new Logger(loggerName)
}
```

This is exactly what I'm using right know, but I'm stuck with a problem because of this pattern. Indeed if the Logging trait is mixed by a class that is derived, the Logger will be used with the name of the most derived class.

Here is an example to clarify myself:

```
class Logger(logName : String){
  def debug( msg : String ) { println("["+logName+"] : "+msg) }
}

trait Logging {
  val loggerName = this.getClass.getName
  @transient lazy val log = new Logger(loggerName)
}

package a {
  class A extends Logging {
    log.debug("log from A")
  }
}

package b {
  import a._
  class B extends A with Logging {
    log.debug("log from B")
  }
}

object LogTest {
  import b._
  def main(args : Array[String]) = {
    val instance = new B
  }
}
```

When I run this program I got:

```
[b.B] : log from A
[b.B] : log from B
```

Instead of:

```
[a.A] : log from A
[b.B] : log from B
```

Has anyone found a solution to this problem ?

Comment: But B IS-A A, so what you're saying is that you want different loggers:
class A { val aLog = Logger(classOf[A]) }
class B extends A { val bLog = Logger(classOf[B]) }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could achieve this effect using loggers in companion objects:

```
object A extends Logging; 
class A { import A._
  log.debug("log from A")
}

object B extends Logging; 
class B extends A  { import B._
  log.debug("log from B")
}
```

Comment: This does not compile (in 2.8.1) when `log` is marked as `protected` in `Logging`. [SLF4S](https://github.com/weiglewilczek/slf4s) and [Grizzled-SLF4J](http://software.clapper.org/grizzled-slf4j/) do this and I'd argue it's the proper visibility. Maybe it's a bug in scalac 2.8.1?

Answer (score 2):

It is my experience that this is most definitely **not the behaviour that you want**.

When you have some class hierarchy which contains method overriding, your logs might be full of lines which look like:

```
13:44:42.654 - AbstractFooService [INFO] : I have a: foo
13:44:42.656 - AbstractFooService [INFO] : I have bar-d my: foo
```

And you will be asking yourself what *concrete* service implementation were you dealing with? If you don't know, how can you be sure what code path was taken to get where you are? Maybe there should have been a 3rd statement nestling inbetween the two:

```
13:44:42.655 - SpecialFooService [INFO] : I want to baz this foo to bar
```

Much easier to debug if the logs contained

```
13:44:42.654 - DefaultFooService [INFO] : I have a: foo
13:44:42.656 - DefaultFooService [INFO] : I have bar-d my: foo
```

Because then you can tell *immediately* that you are using the wrong foo service

Answer (score -1):

This might be obvious, but if you don’t want the `Logging` trait to be inherited, you could simply use a private variable instead of mixing in a trait.

```
class A {
  private val log = Logger(this)
}

class B extends A with Logging {
}
```

or

```
class A extends Logging {
}

class B extends A {
  override lazy val log = // ...
}
```